# plotly - how to modify markers within a trace

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly

how can one alter the appearance of a marker within a trace?

e.g. in the example below how could the opacity for each marker be set to a specific value (e.g based on the opacity_data list)

Seems like this should be possible but I haven't had any success. Thanks in advance for any help,

dusiod

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.graph_objs as go

app = dash.Dash()

x_data = list(range(1,11))
y_data = [i**2 for i in x_data]
opacity_data = [i / i**2 for i in x_data]

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(id='test',
              figure=go.Figure(
                  data=[go.Scatter(
                      x=x_data,
                      y=y_data,
                      mode='markers',
                      opacity=1)]
              ))
])

app.run_server()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it clicked.... the marker specific info is specified in a list within a dictionary as per the bubble chart example below.

[https://plot.ly/python/bubble-charts/][1]

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

trace0 = go.Scatter(
    x=[1, 2, 3, 4],
    y=[10, 11, 12, 13],
    mode='markers',
    marker=dict(
        color=['rgb(93, 164, 214)', 'rgb(255, 144, 14)',
               'rgb(44, 160, 101)', 'rgb(255, 65, 54)'],
        opacity=[1, 0.8, 0.6, 0.4],
        size=[40, 60, 80, 100],
    )
)

data = [trace0]
py.iplot(data, filename='bubblechart-color')
```